# token error in sample post request

Tags: postman

I try to make post request from test tab in Postman for windows:

```
let data1 = {
    url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
    //no errors here
    method: 'POST',
    //no errors

    body: { mode: “raw”, raw: JSON.stringify({ key: “value” })}
    //once again "SyntaxError | Invalid or unexpected token"
};

//next step is supposed to be
pm.sendRequest("https://postman-echo.com/get",function (err, res) {
     console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: The quotes around the `sendRequest` url would work, the ones you have around `raw` and `value` don't look like you entered them on the Postman UI. Were these copy and pasted from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhy Postman didn't get expressions with double quote sign.
My code now works with this syntax:

```
body: { mode: 'raw', raw: JSON.stringify({ key: 'value' })}
```